# Tags per post per user, the user isn't listed.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My main models are that I have users and I have recipes.

I'm trying to implement a tagging structure such that each user can tag a recipe with individual tags. So when viewing a recipe, they would only see tags that they themselves have added.

I created two models hashtags, and hashtagging that is the join table. It is set up as so:

models/hashtags.rb

```
class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hashtaggings
  has_many :recipes, through: :hashtaggings
  has_many :users, through: :hashtaggings
end
```

models/hashtagging.rb

```
class Hashtagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hashtag
  belongs_to :recipe
end
```

models/recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_many :hashtaggings
    has_many :hashtags, through: :hashtaggings
    ....
    def all_hashtags=(name)
      self.hashtags = name.split(",").map do |name|
        Hashtag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
      end
    end

    def all_hashtags
      self.hashtags.map(&:name).join(",")
    end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :hashtaggings
  has_many :hashtags, through: :hashtaggings
  ...
end
```

This works great for creating the hash tags however I'm at a loss for how to incorporate the user aspect of it. How when assigning the tags can I also assign the current user to those tags and then just return those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps, creation and display...

**Creation**

This one is going to be tricky, because you can't simply do something like...

```
@recipe.hashtags.create(name: "Tasty as heck!")
```

...because neither the recipe, nor the hashtag, knows anything about the user. It's a two-step process.

```
class RecipeHashtagsController
   def create
      current_hashtag = Hashtag.find_or_create_by(name: "Scrumptious!")
      current_recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
      hashtagging = Hashtagging.find_or_create_by(hashtag: current_hashtag, user: current_user, recipe: current_recipe)
      # redirect_to somewhere_else...
   end
end
```

A few things I did there:

- I'm using [`find_or_create_by`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) since I'm assuming you don't want either duplicate hashtags or duplicate hashtaggings. You could also just create.
- I'm assuming you have some kind of `current_user` method in ApplicationController or through a gem like Devise.
- I'm assuming you have a controller like RecipeHashtags, and a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) that matches and will provide an `id` from the route. I recommend nesting here since you aren't simply creating a hashtag, but you are creating a hashtag within the specific context of a recipe.

**Displaying**

This gets tricky, because you want to display `recipe.hashtags` but with a condition on the join table hashtaggings. This is not super straightforward.

What I'm thinking is you might want to be able to do something like...

```
@recipe.hashtags_for_user(current_user)
```

...which could be in the form of a method on `Recipe`.

```
class Recipe

  def hashtags_for_user(user)
    Hashtags.joins(:hashtaggings).where(hashtaggings: { user_id: user.id, recipe_id: self.id })
  end

end
```

You can read more about the hash inside the `.where` call in [the Active Record Querying Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) (check out section 12.3).

**Edit: The Controller**

I recommend creating RecipeHashtags as a nested route pointing to separate controller, since the creation of a hashtag is dependent on which recipe it's being created for.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :recipes do
  resources :hashtags, only: [:create]
end
```

...which will show something like the following when you do `rake routes` in the terminal...

```
POST /recipes/:recipe_id/hashtags(.:format) recipe_hashtags#create
```

Note: I'm assuming you have a resource for resource for `recipes`. If you don't, this may duplicate some routes and have other, unintended results.

The default behavior for Rails is to assume you've got a controller like `recipe_hashtags_controller` based on how you defined your resources. You can always override this if you like.

Comment: Thank you soo much! This is incredibly hashtag. I don't have a resource for RecipeHashtags, so I'm guessing I should create one? Is it just a controller basically that will use the other models?

Comment: Yes, I would think so... I'll update my answer in a minute with more details.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. So basically with the nested resource you get the :recipe_id from the url for the creation of it. I do have one final question.  How does this translate to the form for creation? Previously when it was a recipe parameter I could easily fit it into the form, and it doesn't seem like theres a way to keep :all_hashtags as a recipe parameter because theres no way to pass the current_user to the model/ its not recommended. So how do you put this in the form view?

Comment: I think you just have a form for a user to add a hashtag to a recipe. My understanding is that recipes are created globally by some admin (???) and later a user comes along and tags it. That's its own form. If you want to have the person who posts the recipe also to be able to tag the recipe with tags no one else can see, then you'll need to get fancier with form objects. Start here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects